# Affinity law of fans: why is pressure proportional to the square of the radius?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

According to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_laws, when shaft speed is constant, the pressure is proportional to square of impeller diameter.

I am wondering why this is true. Surely, for larger diameter, more air is pumped, so we need a stronger **force**. But why pressure also need to increase?

Comment: IDK, but the article talks about "trimming" an impeller to intentionally degrade its performance, and when one reduces the diameter of the impeller in that way, one does _not_ also reduce the diameter of the housing within which it rotates. Also of note: The article clearly states that the "laws" it describes are only rough approximations and should only be used to predict the effect of _small_ changes in some system variable.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Of course the "laws" are approximate - but I expect them to at least make sense intuitively.